# Spacing Table Cells using CSS/Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is have a grid layout - that you can edit the number of rows/columns you want, and that part works fine for the most part. But whatever I do I can't seem to get the individual cells to space properly. Originally I had it built as a table- but was told divs could behave like a table, and figured they would be easier to manipulate CSS but no avail.

The problems I run into is trying to change the width/padding/margin/etc of the cells to create a spacing, generally warps the height/width of the thumbnail.

Also another problem I had was the spacing between rows seems to just randomly have extra height for no reason-

Is there a better way to go about what I'm trying to do - some sort of simple customizable grid layout or how can I get the spacing to be the way I want it?

Background - still trying to build a customizable image gallery based off jQuery/Javascript so I can create a database to upload images to because I couldn't find anything I liked, here's what I have so far if your interested: http://drewswinson.com/DP/

Comment: @Gazow That page looks OK. Is the issue present on the page?

Comment: not sure what you mean, the thumbnails are all on top of each other

Comment: @Gazow I don't understand. The thumbnails are arranged in two rows with 6 images in each row. It looks fine to me.

Comment: it may look fine to you, but having them sitting on top of each other is not what i want them to do, so it isn't fine at all

Comment: @Gazow But there are side-by-side, not on top of each other.

Comment: you see the spacing in between the rows, thats what i want the columns to have, except the gap between the rows, is some arbitray number the table layout has set itself for some reason, i cant edit it, and i cant add any spacing in between the columns.--- this is what i want it to look like- http://i.imgur.com/J1Nlz.png

Comment: where all of the variables are editable- i need to be able to change the table layout from say 6x2 to 1x8 or something(which is already working) but still have the grid layout for the functions im passing. and i cant seem to get a table style to accept my spacing arguments between them without affecting the size of the thumbnail image

Comment: @Gazow First of all, you're setting 100% widths and heights on the IMG elements, which is not a good idea. I would set the width of the images to a fixed value - like 50px. Next, you didn't set any padding on the "table-cell" elements. Also, I would use TABLE, TR, TD elements, not DIV's.

Comment: I had table /tr/td elements origionally- it was overiding all of the margins i tried to assign

Comment: hrm, well it seems im halfway there, at least its allowing my to add spacing now, but the cell height seems to just do whatever it wants \=

Comment: @Gazow Make sure that you remove 100% height from the images. Set either the width or the height to a fixed value. Once you do that, make sure that the cells have a padding - like padding:5px. Also, set display:block for the images - that should remove the vertical spacing to a degree. I've made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Rmj3w/

Comment: that seemed to help a lot thanks- if you want to put that as an answer i accept. still having a bit of trouble with the random height being overridden betwen the rows

Comment: @Gazow Add this CSS rule to your CSS file: `#thumbs img { display:block; }`. That will correct the vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
        <td> <img src="http://placekitten.com/60/100"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td { padding:6px; }
img { border:3px solid white; display:block; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Rmj3w/